# A good regular expression for an URI in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I want to find all links looking like `http://vk.com` or `https://stackoverflow.com` in my string.

How could I do that via regular expression in Elixir?

Comment: FYI: regex to match URI is [far more complicated](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html) than one could ever imagine.

Comment: I know, but the aim is to find something that can cover 95% of the cases

Comment: Even finding a regex to cover 95% of the cases is far from trivial.  And you're making a boatload of assumptions about what 95% of the URI's you will see will look like.

Answer (score 1):

Elixir regexp for link looks like:

```
regexp = ~r/ https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/
```

So, you can successfully find all links in your string by

```
Regex.scan(regexp, your_string)
```

Comment: The regexp is wrong in many respects. It misses non-HTTP links, TLD with more than 6 characters, domain names with one label, etc. And I don't even mention IDN.